# Two Charts, One Chart Area -- Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I work for a public school system and have been asked to emulate a dashboard like what Atlanta has.  It features two charts that are occupying the same plot/chart area.  On the left side of the chart is a bar graph, on the right side is what I'm assuming is a scatter graph.  The link to this chart is here, the one on the left-hand side:

https://public.tableau.com/views/AttendanceandSuspensions1415/AttendanceDash?:embed=y&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no#1

Is there a way to do this in Highcharts?

Comment: Be aware that your shared project is open and editable to every one!!

Comment: @bub -- I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean...are you talking about the link I shared?

Comment: Yes I am. It is "very" open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can set multiple y axes, and set their positions.
Then you assign each data series to one of the axes.

Example:

```
yAxis: [{  
    left: 120, width: 200,
},{
    offset: 0,
    left: 345, width: 200,
}]
```

.

```
series: [{
  yAxis: 0,
  data: [...]
}, {
  yAxis: 1,
  type: 'scatter',
  data: [...]
}]
```

Example fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j0eq21du/

Comment: That is PERFECT!!  Thank You!!